# JSON response not sent

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have two servers. Server A and server B. I use php, jquery for the programming language, Apache for the web server.

*What I want to achieve:*
There are javascript that call this url http://serverB/someprocess.php, server B response with json whether the process 'someprocess' is TRUE or FALSE

*Problem:*
When I test locally, it works just like I want. But when I upload the script, and when I look at firebug, there are no JSON response from server B, so the script fail.

*Question:*
I had many problem about script work in local but in live before, but this one really confuse me. What should I check? Can you give me any clue?

*Note:* 
'someprocess' is a php script that do process transferring data from progress DB (not postgre) via Merrant ODBC to SQL Server 2000 and it took 70 seconds to finish

*What I have try:*

- set apache timeout to 80 seconds
- change server B response to text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is cross domain ajax request

a solution is like :

[jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP)

or

[proxy way](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html)

Comment: thanks for the jsonp information, i've heard it but never read about this topic any further